# Insert a table in an unalterable format into a Word 2010 file while retaining font size and sharpness

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to insert a table in an unalterable format into a Word 2010 file while retaining font size and sharpness.

So far, I have tried preparing the table as a pdf, then using `Insert` -> `Object` -> `Adobe Acrobat File` to get it into Word.  Unfortunately, this inserts the table within  margins automatically created on the Word page, and distorts lines and font size within the table.

Here are some things I've tried:
- Setting the margins of the page in the recipient Word file to 0" before importing the pdf.
- Printing the pdf on on a smaller page (7" x 9") then importing onto a page 8.5" x 11".
Neither worked; the imported pages were resized and the table printed badly.

The pdf I used was prepared from Word using PrimoPDF.

Please feel free to suggest formats other than pdf for the transfer if they can be more easily incorporated into the final Word document.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prepare the table as a Word document. Go to the `Review` tab, and select `Restrict Editing`. Set `Editing Restrictions` to allow `No changes (Read only)`. Press `Yes, Start Enforcing Protection`. Save file.

Next prepare the recipient document in Word. Go to the `Insert` tab, select `Object`, `Create from File`, and browse to find and insert the file.

The table will be inserted into the recipient Word file as a document within a document, and its 'Read Only' protection is maintained.  All fonts and line styles remain as originally set.